# How to save a stolen jet?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've stolen a jet in the story mode (multiple times now). I've brought it to both hangars (red squares on the picture), but none was saved by the game.

I tried both hangars with Franklin and the one more in the south with Trevor.

Has storing jets been fixed or did I miss something? If I drive into the hangar, nothing happens. If I leave the jet, stay right next to it, save and reload, it will be gone.

I'm playing on PC.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok guys, I found a solution that worked for me. I don't know if there are other ways but this one definitely works:

1. I completed the main story line.
2. I saw that I can buy the hangar in Los Santos, do that (marked as "2." on the map)! Note: If this is possible before completing the main story, the first point will be unnecessary.
3. Steal a jet from the military base (marked as "1." on the map). I used Franklin and his ability to slow down time during driving. Watch youtube videos on how to get away. I flew in a spiral-like way. Don't kill the guards, just drive past them, stop near a jet, go in and leave asap. I had to reload several times before I finally got the drift.
4. Bring it to your hangar.
5. Done, from now on you can destroy it and it will respawn there. I have no idea why the other hangars didn't work.

[image]

Comment: It seems to have problem with store fighter jet with buy one. I buy one plane and then steal fighter jet as you said and put it in hangar and save. Exit the game, come back in and go to hangar and there it is. Go to other place and go back to hangar. It's gone. GONE! Nooo!!

Comment: @vee NOOOOOOOO!!!! :'o ... Uh, but why did u buy one?

Comment: I have no idea why did I buy? Just buy.

Comment: @vee oh well there u go m8. buy if you can afford and afford if you can buy u know? having nothing in the hangar sux and is bad for flying

Answer (score 1):

I found that with Trevor's second hangar, if you steal a fighter jet and park it as far back in the hangar as possible, then steals another and park it in front of that one then they both save and the one in the front respawns.

Answer (score 0):

I just stole a jet from Los Santos Airport and flew it to the Trevor's hangar (the bigger one) and it got saved somehow, even though I blew it up. Now I can fly with it anytime I want because it always respawns. Try for yourselves!